# One to many join, displaying client list and it's client status based on other tables column

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I have 2 tables with the following format & data:

Drives table:

```
id  timestamp           user    driver  client  vehicle departure               destination                         distance    type        payment_type    total   expenses    profit  debt    note
26  2014-01-21 14:56:00 146     10      17      27      Lewforos Athinwn 209    Aerolimenas Athinwn El. Venizelos   60          Diadromi    Cash            50      40          10      0       Aida...
```

Clients table:

```
id  user    name    surname         region  address         vat         tax_office  phone       fax         mobile      email                   registered           note
1   146     Maria   Papadopoulou    Alimos  Lisikratous 37  137890567   P.Falirou   2109859786  2109857683  6944536784  maria.pap@domain.com    2013-10-29 13:00:07  some test!
```

The connection between those 2 tables is `drives.client = clients.id`
1 client can have many drives.

At the moment I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT clients.id,
CONCAT(LEFT(clients.name, 1), '.  ', clients.surname) AS client_name,
clients.region,
clients.address,
clients.phone,
clients.fax,
clients.mobile,
clients.email,
CASE
    WHEN DATE(drives.timestamp) < DATE(NOW()) THEN
        CASE 
            WHEN drives.debt = 0 THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN drives.total > 0 THEN 'Completed'
                    WHEN drives.total = 0 THEN 'Pending'
                END
            WHEN drives.debt > 0 THEN 'Overdue'
        END
    WHEN DATE(drives.timestamp) >= DATE(NOW()) THEN 'Scheduled'
    ELSE ''
END AS payment_status,                       
clients.registered,
DATE_FORMAT(clients.registered, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS stamp
FROM clients
LEFT OUTER JOIN drives ON clients.id = drives.client 
WHERE clients.user
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a list of all the clients printing each client once and only once and if he has a drive with status pending, overdue, or scheduled to show up as payment status or alternatively a separate column for each client to show how many overdue , pending and scheduled drives has

**Desired results would be(row):**

```
client.id client.name client.surname client.overdue client.pending client.scheduled
```

Comment: Please show an example of your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overall query needs a `group by` clause, if you want to see things at the client level.  The following counts the number of "drives" in each of the categories.  It is based on the logic in the query in your question:

```
SELECT c.id, CONCAT(LEFT(c.name, 1), '.  ', c.surname) AS client_name,
       c.region, c.address, c.phone, c.fax, c.mobile, c.email,
       sum(CASE WHEN DATE(d.timestamp) < DATE(NOW()) and
                     d.debt = 0 and
                     d.total > 0
                THEN 1 else 0
           end) as Completed,
       sum(CASE WHEN DATE(d.timestamp) < DATE(NOW()) and
                     d.debt = 0 and
                     d.total = 0
                THEN 1 else 0
           end) as Pending,
       sum(CASE WHEN DATE(d.timestamp) < DATE(NOW()) and
                     d.debt > 0
                THEN 1 else 0
           end) as OverDue,
       sum(CASE WHEN DATE(d.timestamp) >= DATE(NOW()) and
                     d.debt > 0
                THEN 1 else 0
           end) as Scheduled,
      c.registered,
      DATE_FORMAT(c.registered, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS stamp
FROM clients c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     drives d
     ON c.id = d.client 
GROUP BY c.id;
```